# ¿Cómo refrescar automáticamente un ListView Builder de imágenes url en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

Tengo un ListView en flutter que muestra imágenes url de cámaras online. Las imágenes se actualizan cada X segundos en el servidor, pero no logro que se actualicen en la aplicación.

Las url son estáticas, es decir lo que cambia es la imagen de la cámara pero la url siempre será la misma por lo que no tengo que hacer ninguna petición HTTP. Aún así he falseado una peticion async unida a un Timer para intentar refrescar los datos pero no he logrado nada.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok eso es porque la URL es la misma y está haciendo caching internamente.

Esta bien que uses el timer si es que quieres refrescarlo cada X segundos aunque lo mejor sería websockets, que cada vez que haya algún cambio, se actualice el tiempo real.

Ahora para que el widget de imagen sepa que es una URL diferente, podrías agregarle un parametro extra, por ejemplo, si tu imagen es esta:

https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/1/13/MUI_Goku_FighterZ.png/revision/latest?cb=20200814014756&path-prefix=protagonist

Podrías agregarle al final:

https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/1/13/MUI_Goku_FighterZ.png/revision/latest?cb=20200814014756&path-prefix=protagonist&123456

Para que sea variable, podrías generar la fecha actual en millisegundos y concatenarla:

[https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/1/13/MUI_Goku_FighterZ.png/revision/latest?cb=20200814014756&path-prefix=protagonist&[FechaEnMilisegundos]](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/p__/images/1/13/MUI_Goku_FighterZ.png/revision/latest?cb=20200814014756&path-prefix=protagonist&%5BFechaEnMilisegundos%5D)

Comment: Muchas gracias, investigaré los websockets, pero tu solución funcionó

Comment: Dale bro :), te invito a mi canal :  www.youtube.com/diegoveloper , flutter al siguiente nivel